# Python: List with [< >, <>...]

Tags: python, pysvn

I'm using PySVN to get diff between 2 links, and the function I'm using returns a list with '<>':

```
[<PysvnDiffSummary u'sdk_include/EthernetScannerSDK.h'>, <PysvnDiffSummary u'sdk_include/EthernetScannerSDKDefine.h'>, <PysvnDiffSummary u'sdk_include/CMakeLists.txt'>]
```

What exactly is this type of data? And how can I acces only the part after " ' "? (E.G. from < PysvnDiffSummary u'sdk_include/EthernetScannerSDK.h' > I only want sdk_include/EthernetScannerSDK.h, without using .split(' \' ') if possible.

Comment: What you're seeing is `repr` representation of `PysvnDiffSummary` objects. Looking at the source code you can get the required value using the `.__name` attribute of individual objects: https://github.com/xiewandongqq/subversion_for_sublime_txt3/blob/56647080a3d3dd96389109ef6aa04d7e42f3f76d/pysvn/__init__.py.template#L38

Comment: You will find that this is all documented in ther pysvn programmers reference guide that is always install along with the pysvn kit: http://pysvn.tigris.org/docs/pysvn_prog_ref.html

Comment: pysvn.tigris has been down for a while, but you can also find the docs inside your python installation's site-packages: Python27/Lib/site-packages/pysvn/pysvn_prog_ref.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a representation of PySvnDiffSummary object. Try using dir(Object) to get it's attributes and from there. It's probably going to be something like object.url

so when you find out what the attribute is (from comments elsewhere, it's `__name`), you'll want something like:

```
urls = [sumary.__name for summary in list]
```

Working list with just what you want :)

Comment: Use list comprehension and `__name` attribute as proposed by Ashwini : `urls = [summary.__name for summary in list]`

Comment: It worked! I honestly did not know about 'dir(Object)' which seems to be a very helpful.
Finally, I've got this many options (I'll write them down here in a sec.)

    ['__add__', '__class__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', '__delitem__', '__delslice__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__getslice__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__iadd__', '__imul__', '__init__', '__iter__', '__le__', '__len__', '__lt__', '__mul__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__reversed__', '__rmul__', '__setattr__', '__setitem__',

Comment: some of them are python builtins, in Ashwini's comment there's a link to a source, it's probably easier to read from there :]

Comment: Yeah,
Finally, 'path' is what I was looking for. Thanks all for help!